# how to indent the following prints

Tags: python, text, word-wrap

lets say I have someone else's function which does the following:

```
def print_numbers(N):
    for i in range(N):
        print(i,'- something something')
```

now **without changing the function** I would like to call it from outside such that it will be printed with initial indentation (for simplicity lets say `\t`) as such:

```sh
Here are some random numbers:
     0 - something something
     1 - something something
     2 - something something
     3 - something something
     4 - something something
```

I tried something like this:

```py
print('Here are some random numbers:')
with textwrap.set_indent('\t'):
    print_numbers(5)
```

But I couldn't find such method..
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
def print_numbers(N):
    for i in range(N):
        print(i,'- something something')

def special_print(*args):
    pf('\t', *args)

pf = print # save reference to original built-in
print = special_print # override
print_numbers(5)
print = pf # reset built-in
```